# Importing layout position for a graph using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am very new to Networkx. I am trying to import layout position generated by `random_layout()` function. I dont know how to do proceed with it.

Code to generate layout position:

```
G = nx.random_geometric_graph(10, 0.5)
pos = nx.random_layout(G)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'pos', pos)
f = open("graphLayout.txt", 'wb')
f.write("%s" % pos)
f.close()
print pos
filename = "ipRandomGrid.txt"
fh = open(filename, 'wb')
nx.write_adjlist(G, fh)
#nx.write_graphml(G, sys.stdout)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
fh.close()
```

File: ipRandomGrid.txt

```
# GMT Tue Dec 06 04:28:27 2011
# Random Geometric Graph
0 1 3 4 6 8 9 
1 3 4 6 8 9 
2 4 7 
3 8 6 
4 5 6 7 8 
5 8 9 6 7 
6 7 8 9 
7 9 
8 9 
9
```

I am storing both node `adjlist` and the layout in files. Now I want to generate the graph with the same layout and `adjlist` from other file. I tried to generate it with the below code. Can anyone help me to figure out what is wrong over here.

Code while importing:
Pseudo Code

```
G = nx.Graph() 
G = nx.read_adjlist("ipRandomGrid.txt")
# load POS value from file 
nx.draw(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=['1','2'], node_color='b')
plt.show()
```

Comment: We need two more things in order to help you. 1) An example of the file data. 2) Any error messages that you see when running your script.

Comment: (1) File: ipRandomGrid.txt
    `# GMT Tue Dec 06 04:28:27 2011
    # Random Geometric Graph
    0 1 3 4 6 8 9 
    1 3 4 6 8 9 
    2 4 7 
    3 8 6 
    4 5 6 7 8 
    5 8 9 6 7 
    6 7 8 9 
    7 9 
    8 9 
    9`

(2) First code running fine. Second one I dont to how to finish it.

Answer (score 0):

The `nx.random_layout` function returns a dictionary mapping nodes to positions. As `pos` is a Python object, you don't want to just store the printed string version of it to a file, as you did in `f.write("%s" % pos)`. This gives you a file containing your dictionary, but reading it back in isn't as easy.

Instead, serialize `pos` using one of the standard library modules designed for that task, for example, `json` or `pickle`. Their interfaces are basically the same, so I'll just show how to do it with `pickle`. Storing is:

```
with open("graphLayout.txt", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(pos, f)
```

Reloading is:

```
with open("graphLayout.txt", 'rb') as f:
    pos = pickle.load(f)
```